# Writing variables with .write() Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to write a string + datetime to a text file with Python. I'm trying to make a basic logger, that will log the datetime in a format of; "Full weekday, day number, Full month name, full year, 12 hour format, minute, second, AM/PM, UTC". I read that file.write() can only take strings and not integers or dates etc. So how would I would I make this work to be written to the text file?

```
grab_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d, %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z")
firstline = "Log Created: ", grab_date, "/nLog deleted and recreated."
f = open("gen-log.txt", "w")
f.seek(0)
f.write(firstline)
f.close()
```

EDIT: not quite sure why but I read on one post that f.seek(0) did something and it worked for them. lol. I just left it in there. Sorry.

Comment: What you're doing with `fileline = foo, bar, baz` is setting `fileline` to a tuple of three values. You can't `write` a tuple, only a string. (The fact that `print` can take a bunch of comma-separated arguments is because `print` is a special statement.)

Comment: why are you opening and then using seek?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write your own logger instead of using the `logging` module? There are a whole lot of other things to deal with that you haven't even begun to approach (like appending instead of overwriting and/or moving the old file out of the way, and wrapping things up in a single function call so you don't have to write 6 lines of code for each log message, and deciding whether to keep the file open or reopen/close with each message or batch them up, and so on).

Comment: @abarnet just because you see only 6 lines of code doesnt mean thats all thats there. I have it in a function, and a bunch of other code. I just took the snippet that wasn't working. Python isnt the first programming language I know. Dont judge a book by its cover yo but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your data into a string; with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), for example:

```
firstline = "Log Created: {}/nLog deleted and recreated.".format(grab_date)
```

You can also make use of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)'s ability to convert all arguments to a string and automatic newlines, and have *it* write to the file:

```
print("Log Created:", grab_date, file=f)
print("Log deleted and recreated.", file=f)
```

If you can avoid it, don't reinvent the logging wheel and use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). It can be [configured to take a different date format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(datefmt="%A %d, %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", format='Log Created: %(asctime)-15s %(message)s')
>>> logging.warn('Foo bar baz!')
Log Created: Monday 28, July 2014 08:13:44 PM BST Foo bar baz!
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would it be worth using logging when all im really adding to the text file is just a few errors?

Comment: @catalyst: sure, `logging` is easy to use and gives you a lot of flexibility *later* when you may need more control. The module gives you that for free.